# Select checkbox from excel with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, checkbox, watir

I would like to select a checkbox from an excel spreadsheet for a data driven test.

code for the checkbox:

```
Not Checked:

<input type="checkbox" class="greenopt" name="Accounts[0][greenopt]" id="" value="0"> 

Checked:

<input type="checkbox" class="greenopt" name="Accounts[0][greenopt]" id="" value="1">
```

I tried the following but get the error: Unable to locate element, using {:value=>"1"}

```
greenopt_check=worksheet.cells(rows,"O").value 
browser.checkbox(:value => greenopt_check).set
```

this is kind of similar to my previous question regarding radio buttons
[Select Radio buttons from excel with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082606/select-radio-buttons-from-excel-with-ruby)

Comment: is the HTML code above for the same checkbox?  is the checkbox value changing when the checkbox is selected?
 We may need to see more of the HTML to make much sense of this, for example how does a user know which checkbox they are selecting and what it does?  knowing how the user determines what checkbox to tick may lead us to a good way to have Watir identify the checkbox.

Comment: what is wrong with >> browser.checkbox(class => 'greenopt').set

Comment: without seeing more of the page we don't know if it's unique.  But @DaveMcNulla I have to admit, going after the Name or the Class as a way to identify the right checkbox would be my first inclination.  Name is just a tiny bit more likely to be unique, since I've seen class get re-used a fair bit when it's used to trigger CSS styles for formatting and appearance.   but without more HTML we don't know which is a better option or if they are equivalent

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden When I am writing my classes, I put more thought into it than I did here (so little info). I make sure it's not a duplicate like class can be, or a dynamic identifier like ID's/indexes are. In this case, I was wondering why he chose a dynamic identifier.

Comment: there is only one checkbox on this page and the html above is the same for the checkbox. The only thing that is changing is the value.... 0 for unchecked 1 of checked. I added 0 and 1 in my excel spreadsheet. I tried using "class" and "name" for my identifier.

Comment: What happened when you tried class and name? If you are stingy with the information, people will stop volunteering to help you.

Comment: I got the same error Unable to locate element, using {:value=>"1"}. It is definitely pulling from the .xlsx file but it is not setting the value of the checkbox to "1"

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should to forget the spreadsheet until you can find and set the checkbox. When that is successful, then you can retrieve the search values from the spreadsheet. And the information you are providing is still sparse. You will help those helping you if you treat this like a defect that you are documenting.

Comment: I can fin and set the checkbox fine without using the spreadsheet. I can find it by using browser.checkbox(:class => 'greenopt').set and it will set the checkbox with a value of '1'.  So the issue is trying to get the value to set to one through the spreadsheet. The HTML code above seems to me that the logical thing to do would eb to set the value but the watir exception is throwing the error. I dont know what other information you are looking for but i do appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: You just told us that value is changing, so why in the world would you try to select the checkbox according to value? (which is what the code you showed above is doing).  If it works to select by class or name, then use that instead, not 'value'   See dave's answer

Comment: the reason why i trying to set the checkbox according to value is because on some iterations of the test I did not want to have it checked. That is why i was trying to set it through the value.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you would be getting an error if you try to select by something that is not found.  If the objective is to be able to either clear or set the checkbox, then you would want another column where you read some kind of 'action' and use conditional logic (if/then or case) in your test code to take the appropriate action at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the [watir checkbox documentation](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/CheckBox.html). in that case you can checkbox.set or checkbox.clear depending on your goals.

You want to use something that is unique, and consistent/predictable to select elements

```
checkbox_class = worksheet.cells(rows,"A").value
puts 'retrieved checkbox_class from spreadsheet is:' + checkbox_class #for debugging, make sure you got the correct thing from the spreadsheet
browser.checkbox(:class => checkbox_class).set
```

or

```
checkbox_name = worksheet.cells(rows,"A").value
puts 'retrieved checkbox_name from spreadsheet is:' + checkbox_name #for debugging, make sure you got the correct thing from the spreadsheet
browser.checkbox(:name => checkbox_name).set
```

Comment: @ChuckvdL I don't mind a bit, especially from a pro like you.